# Boot Zero W from USB device

Tags: boot, bootloader, pi-zero-w

The older Raspberry Pi's (Pi 1, Pi 2 and Pi Zero) couldn't boot from a USB-device, but the [Raspberry Pi 3 has support for it](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pi-3-booting-part-i-usb-mass-storage-boot/). The Pi and Pi 2 have semi-support for it ([using an SD-card with a single bootfile](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/tree/master/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes#special-bootcodebin-only-boot-mode)). The Pi Zero W is a remake of their older boards but it's newer than the Pi 3.

Is the Raspberry Pi Zero W fully compatible with the new bootcode? Can the Raspberry Pi Zero W boot from USB without using an SD card?

Comment: This may be of some use: [usbboot](https://github.com/raspberrypi/usbboot). VIDEO: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm1WUY5XgrQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: This is possible if the Zero/Zero W is set up to act as a USB *device* and gets the boot files from a host machine that it's plugged into. See [Janghou's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/76131) below for details.

The rest of this post applies to booting the Zero W when it is acting as a USB *host*, which appears to be what the original question was asking.

---

Not with no SD card at all. The Pi Zero W uses a BCM2835, which contains the old SD card-only bootloader. It's not so much a question of the Pi being older or newer as of which processor it uses.

Also, [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=144165&start=50) states that they can only really give the BCM2835/BCM2836* a new bootloader if somebody is willing to donate a LOT of money to create a new mask rom that could be used to program the chips.

However, as Toothbrush pointed out in the comments, you can use an SD card with just [`bootcode.bin`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/raw/master/boot/bootcode.bin) on it and you will be able to boot from a USB device.

*The now out of production BCM2836, which was used in the Pi 2 until that model [switched to use the BCM2837](http://raspi.tv/2016/new-raspberry-pi-2b-1-2-with-pi3-bcm2837-processor), uses the old bootloader as well.

Comment: My Pi Zero W (and Pi 3) got delivered today and I can confirm that you are correct.

Comment: If you copy only `bootcode.bin` onto the SD card, you can [boot from a USB mass storage device](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/host.md). See https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/README.md#special-bootcodebin-only-boot-mode for details.

Comment: @Toothbrush, the question states "without using an SD card." That implies no SD card at all, not even just for boot files.

Comment: @anonymoose Yes, my intention was to note that you could boot from USB, even on those old devices which do not natively support it. You could potentially buy a very cheap 64MB MicroSD card. Also, please note that Max asks **two** questions. "Is the new Raspberry Pi Zero W fully compatible with the new bootcode?" – Not without a MicroSD card. "Can the Raspberry Pi Zero W boot from USB without using an SD card?" – No, not without an SD card with bootcode.bin.

Comment: @Toothbrush True. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Toothbrush as the resources seem to have expired - all that's required is that binary file on the sd card and then `dd if=raspbian.img of=/dev/sdX` and it should boot?

Comment: @php_nub_qq Yes, you can find the details at https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#special-bootcode-bin-only-boot-mode.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

You can boot an RPI Zero without a SD card through an USB cable connected with a PC.

You need `Raspberry Pi USB booting code` that is available [here on Github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/usbboot) or can be installed on a RPI or Raspberry Desktop computer (PC) running Stretch.

It's available since the [Stretch update](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/stretch-pcs-macs-raspbian-update/) of 2017-12:

```
sudo apt-get install usbbootgui
```

Just connect a RPI Zero with an USB cable in the USB OTG and **without** an SD card, a GUI will pop-up:

- GPIO expansion board
- eMMC /SD card reader
- Custom application

For [accessing GIO pins](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/gpio-expander/).

Is should be possible to boot Stretch (or any other application) through USB, although I've not seen a working example yet.

A first step into booting Stretch Lite (crashes when looking for the rootfs) can be achieved with:

```
# setup a Loop device and scan partition table
sudo losetup -P /dev/loop0 ~/Downloads/2017-11-29-raspbian-stretch-lite.img
# if loop device busy try /dev/loop1
# mount the loop device boot partition
sudo mount /dev/loop0p1/ /media/pi/
# boot the pi zero from the mounted image
sudo rpiboot -d /media/pi/
```

The pi Zero will boot and show the red Raspberry Icon, but there it stops.

This [blog-post](https://dev.webonomic.nl/how-to-run-or-boot-raspbian-on-a-raspberry-pi-zero-without-an-sd-card) describes how to boot Raspbian Stretch on a Zero without an SD card.

Comment: Is it possible to do this from a Mac?

Comment: I guess it is, it's all open source. I guess, you need to compile usbbootgui, and mount an image on a  nfs-server, or try a ubuntu virtual machine.

Comment: I've been trying to recreate your blog post however `usbboot` doesn't recognize a new device when I plug in my Zero W. Do I have to put it into device mode first? If so, is that possible without an SD card?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is "No, and no."

Raspberry Pi Zero W was released newer than the Pi 3. But Raspberry Pi Zero W use older chip--BCM2835.
It can do same thing as you mentioned--The Pi and Pi 2, and Pi Zero W have semi-support for it (using an SD-card with a single bootfile).

I appreciate all the answers but when I am reading answers it made me more confusing than what was asked--I think because I am quite beginner in the Raspberry Pi.

So I think it might helpful for beginner like me.